# Is there a quick way to download a directory in a repo?

Tags: centos, repository

I'm actually working from a *windows* machine, attempting to retrieve **centOS 5.4** from their vault. I don't have unpacking software, so I don't want to use the iso's. I was wondering if there's an easy way to grab all of the contents of  [this](http://vault.centos.org/5.4/os/i386/) directory inside a browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `wget` ([for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)) (or via [cgywin](https://www.cygwin.com/)) to download the site recursively,

```
$ wget -c \
     --recursive \
     --no-clobber \
     --page-requisites \
     --html-extension \
     --convert-links \
     --restrict-file-names=windows \
     --domains vault.centos.org \
     --no-parent \
     http://vault.centos.org/5.4/os/i386/
```

The options are:

```
--recursive: download the entire Web site.
--domains vault.centos.org: don't follow links outside vault.centos.org.
--no-parent: don't follow links outside the directory tutorials/html/.
--page-requisites: get all the elements that compose the page (images, CSS and so on).
--html-extension: save files with the .html extension.
--convert-links: convert links so that they work locally, off-line.
--restrict-file-names=windows: modify filenames so that they will work in Windows as well.
--no-clobber: don't overwrite any existing files (used in case the download is interrupted and resumed).
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It defined one robots.txt, the following is its content: User-agent: *
Disallow: /