# wget to get all the files in a directory only returns index.html

Tags: command-line, wget

I'm new to using bash, and I have been trying to `wget` all the files from a website to the server I have been working on. However all I'm getting back is an `index.html` file. I let it run for 15 minutes and the index.html file was still downloading so I killed it. Might my files be download after the `index.html` file?

Here is the code I have been trying:

```
$ wget --no-parent -R index.html -A "Sample" -nd --random-wait \
   -r -p -e robots=off -U Mozilla --no-check-certificate \
   http://somewebsite.com/hasSamples/Sample0
```

I'm trying to download all the files in a subdirectory that starts with Sample. I have searched quite a bit on the internet to find a resolution, and at this point I'm stumped. I probably just haven't found the right combinations of options, but any help would be much appreciated. Here is my understanding of the code:

- `--no-parent` means don't search parent directories
- `-R index.html` means reject downloading the index.html file, I also tried "index.html*", but it still downloaded it anyway
- `-A "Sample"` kind of acts like a Sample* would in bash
- `-nd` means download the files and not any of the directories
- `--random-wait` to make sure you don't get blacklisted from a site
- `-r` recursively downloads
- `-p` not sure really
- `-e robots=off` ignores robot.txt files
- `U Mozilla` makes the user look like its Mozilla I think
- The `--no-check-certificate` is just necessary for the website.

Comment: You can start by replace: `--no-check-  certificate`, by: `--no-check-certificate`.

Comment: oops my bad. I must have added those spaces while typing it out on here. Its not like that in my code. I'll edit it momentarily

Comment: see this question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143996/is-there-a-quick-way-to-download-a-directory-in-a-repo/144030#144030

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> -A "Sample" kind of acts like a Sample* would in bash

Not by my reading of `man wget`:

> - -A acclist --accept acclist
> - -R rejlist --reject rejlist
>
> Specify comma-separated lists of file name suffixes or patterns to accept or reject. Note that if
>              any of the wildcard characters, *, ?, [ or ], appear in an element of acclist or rejlist, *it will
>              be treated as a pattern, **rather than a suffix**.*

So your usage (no wildcards) is equivalent to the bash glob `*.Sample`.

Wget works by scanning links, which is probably why it is trying to download an `index.html` (you haven't said what the content of that is, if any, just that it took a long time) -- it has to have somewhere to start.  To explain further: *an URL is **not** a file path*.  You **cannot** scan a web server as if it were a directory hierarchy, saying, "give me all the files in directory `foobar`". If`foobar` corresponds to a real directory (it certainly doesn't have to, because it's part of an URL, not a file path), a web server *may* be configured to provide an autogenerated index.html listing the files, providing the illusion that you can browse the filesystem.  But that's not part of the HTTP protocol, it's just a convention used by default with servers like apache.  So what `wget` does is scan, e.g., `index.html` for `<a href=` and `<img src=`, etc., then it follows those links and does the same thing, recursively.  That's what wget's "recursive" behaviour refers to -- it recursively scans links because (to reiterate), *it does not have access to any filesystem on the server, and the server does not have to provide it with ANY information regarding such*.

If you have an actual `.html` web page that you can load and click through to all the things you want, start with that address, and use just `-r -np -k -p`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you connect to the page with your browser?

If you browse the pages without any problem, then there might be a couple of things you're missing.

The page might be checking your browser, and Mozilla is not the correct answer, pick one of the browser strings from [here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) (the whole string, not just Mozilla) and try to see if it works.

If it doesn't then you might need cookies, get the cookies connecting to the main page with `wget` and store them. Then use `wget` with those cookies and try to download the pages.

Try `--mirror` option if you want to mirror it.

If nothing works, then I would study the connection and the pages. The live http headers add on for Firefox is a pretty cool tool. You can see the whole communication between your browser and the web page. Try to mimmic that behaviour with wget to obtain what you're looking for.

Comment: I forgot, another important thing, you might need the referer.

Comment: I browse the page without problem. I'll look into your suggestions and get back to you. Thanks for all of your help